# Golang JSON decoder does not recognize type

Tags: json, go

Still a Golang beginner, I am trying to code a generic function to serve ReST requests. I pass a function to create a new resource (struct) with an interface implemented on it, because I would also invoke methods on the struct. When decoding the JSON, logging the type shows the correct (struct) type, but the JSON decoder seems to only recognize the interface, which it cannot decode to.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

// general resource interface
type resource interface {
    // check semantics and return an array of errors or nil if no error found
    check() []string
    // update the resource in backend
    update() error
}

// specific resource named "anchor"
type anchor struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func newAnchor() resource {
    return anchor{}
}

func (a anchor) check() []string {
    return nil
}

func (a anchor) update() error {
    return nil
}

// generic function to create (POST) a new resource
func restCreate(newResource func() resource) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        const F = "restCreate"
        var checkErrs []string

        res := newResource()
        log.Printf("%s res type %T\n", F, res)
        dcdr := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        err := dcdr.Decode(&res)
        log.Printf("%s Unmarshalled into %T: %+v\n", F, res, res)
        if err == nil {
            checkErrs = res.check()
        }
        switch {
        case err != nil:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            log.Printf("[ERR] %s: %v\n", F, err)
        case checkErrs != nil:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            w.Write([]byte(strings.Join(checkErrs, "\n")))
            log.Printf("%s: %v\n", F, err)
        default:
            res.update()
            bs, _ := json.Marshal(res)
            w.Write(bs)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    r := httprouter.New()
    r.POST("/anchors", restCreate(newAnchor))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

The execution log shows:

restCreate res type **main.anchor**
restCreate Unmarshalled into main.anchor: {ID: Name:}
[ERR] restCreate: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type **main.resource**

Why does Printf show the struct type and json.Decoder the interface?
I'd appreciate any indicator on what's going wrong and how to solve this in a generic way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you try to use a pointer to the interface to unmarshal into. You need return a pointer in a function

```
func newAnchor() resource {
    return &anchor{}
}
```

And you don't need to get address in this line:
`err := dcdr.Decode(&res)`

Here is small working example: https://play.golang.org/p/3E0RmGTURO

Comment: That works - thanks Pavlo. Just a bit confused why you can return both the composed literal and it's adress, will explore this further.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Unmarshal into an interface unless variable is holding a pointer to the concrete type you desire, as `json.Decode` won't know which concrete type to use. You have two workarounds at your disposal:

Having `newResource` return a concrete type under the hood:

```
func newResource() resource {
    return &anchor{}
}
```

This way `json.Decode` knows to unmarshal your JSON into an `anchor`.

Use `newAnchor` instead of `newResource`: this will be more readable in your `restCreate` function, and is more idiomatic[1].

[1] http://idiomaticgo.com/post/best-practice/accept-interfaces-return-structs/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to use "restCreate" for a number of different concrete structs, but your answer (and Pavlo's) solved the issue.

Comment: After reading up on the link you provided, I think the author is arguing for the exact solution I implemented - use interfaces on underlying concrete types. Thanks again for the information provided!